# Hide WebView on OSX

Tags: webview

I have a View which tracks mouse with TrackingArea and Mouse Enter/Exit Events, now i want to hide the WebView on my Window whenever the Mouse exits the Window but i cannot tell the WebView to hide, i tried all the googled settings for hidden, set hidden etc , but even "bounds" are undeclared for the WebView in my myView.m Class

I tried to ensure the WebView is known in the MyView.m Class so i can refer to it, but this settings are not available,, even not width, height etc, set AlphaValue is unknown as well, is there any other way to hide a WebView?

thx for help

Answer (score 0):

I solved this my way, its maybe not the right way but it works:

Basically it runs through all subviews and checks if one is the web view, if it is, it assigns it to a variable , refs it and hides it:

```
NSArray *subviews = [self subviews];
for (NSView *subview in subviews) {
    if(subview.bounds.size.height == 495){
        subview.hidden = NO;
    }
}
```

this is surely not the right way, but its a way it works